# boost::hash for tuple containing boost units

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-units, boost-functional

I want to use a `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` with a key of `std::tuple<A...>` where `A...` will include boost unit types. The HashCompare struct I'm using at the moment looks like this:

```
template<typename K>
struct HashCompare {
    static size_t hash( const K& key )
    {
        boost::hash<K> hasher;
        return hasher(key);
    }
    static bool equal( const K& key1, const K& key2 ) {return key1 == key2;}
};
```

For all non boost unit types I tried this worked nicely but not so with boost units. I know that it is possible to extend the `boost::hash` function with custom types but I seem unable to do that. As i have quite a lot of units I wanted to do this with a template of the following form:

```
std::size_t hash_value(T const& t){
    boost::hash<double> hasher;
    return hasher(t.value());
}
```

Putting this function in the `boost` namespace or in the namespace where the units are defined didn't work.

How is it possible to extend the boost hashing function to custom types or write a template for the `HashCompare::hash` function that takes only boost units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed Boost Units does not have hash support. You can add it:

```
template <typename... T>
size_t hash_value(boost::units::quantity<T...> const& q) {
    using boost::hash_value; // enable ADL
    return hash_value(q.value());
}
```

Smallest demo:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef3966b5a2260688)**

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>

#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::hash_value;

template <typename... T>
size_t hash_value(boost::units::quantity<T...> const& q) {
    using boost::hash_value; // enable ADL
    return hash_value(q.value());
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost::units::si;
    auto l  = 23.0*meter;
    auto dt = 2.0*second;

    std::cout << (l) << "\n";
    std::cout << (dt) << "\n";
    std::cout << (l/dt) << "\n";

    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
    std::cout << hash_value(l) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash_value(dt) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash_value(l/dt) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
23 m
2 s
11.5 m s^-1
0x4037000000000000
0x4000000000000000
0x4027000000000000
```

### Using with `boost::hash` in generic code

Make sure the overload is accessible on the point of instantiation. Enable argument dependent lookup (ADL):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5276bd864b04366)**

```
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>

#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

namespace boost::units {
    template <typename... T>
    size_t hash_value(quantity<T...> const& q) {
        using boost::hash_value; // enable ADL
        return hash_value(q.value());
    }
}

namespace detail {
    template<typename K>
        struct HashCompare {
            static size_t hash( const K& key )
            {
                boost::hash<K> hasher;
                return hasher(key);
            }
            static bool equal( const K& key1, const K& key2 ) {return key1 == key2;}
        };

    template <typename T>
    size_t test_mycompare(T const& v) {
        return HashCompare<T>::hash(v);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost::units::si;
    using boost::hash_value;

    auto l  = 23.0*meter;
    auto dt = 2.0*second;

    std::cout << (l) << "\n";
    std::cout << (dt) << "\n";
    std::cout << (l/dt) << "\n";

    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
    std::cout << hash_value(l) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash_value(dt) << "\n";
    std::cout << hash_value(l/dt) << "\n";

    std::cout << detail::test_mycompare(l) << "\n";
    std::cout << detail::test_mycompare(dt) << "\n";
    std::cout << detail::test_mycompare(l/dt) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
23 m
2 s
11.5 m s^-1
0x4037000000000000
0x4000000000000000
0x4027000000000000
0x4037000000000000
0x4000000000000000
0x4027000000000000
```